# Какие документы ведутся при разработке ПО?

Tags: шаблоны-документов

Прошу помощи, так как только вливаюсь в эту тему, а по запросу в интернете мне выдаются только ГОСТы и постановления. Подскажите, какие документы оформляются во во время разработки ПО. Например, сейчас мне необходимо сделать документ, который будет содержать информацию о том, какие дополнительные функции необходимо реализовать в уже существующем проекте. Подскажите, как правильно будет называться этот документ? Какие еще есть документы, сопутствующие разработке. Буду благодарен любой информации

Comment: это ТЗ (которое иногда называется ФТ - функц.требования)

Comment: Техническое задание этот документ называется. однако, не ясно, кому вы этот документ будете направлять, одно дело в соседний отдел вашей организации, другое - подрядчику с которым заключаете договор на разработку.

Comment: @teran, большое спасибо, на данный момент только формируется предприятие, документ был запрошен директором, поэтому и интересуюсь, какие в дальнейшем потребуются документы. Возможно Вы подскажите, какие еще документы требуются от тех.лида или где это можно узнать? Только-только начинаю заступать на должность, много вопросов и непонятно, за что браться сначала, а что придет со временем

Comment: но ведь в ГОСТ как раз и расписано что и как должно быть оформлено

Comment: Зарплатную ведомость не забудьте. Критический для разработки документ. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле набор документов часто очень индивидуален и зависит от того, на сколько сложный продукт разрабатывается. Начиная с технического задания в котором вы опишите процессы как реализованы сейчас на предприятии и как будет после завершения вашего проекта.
Понадобятся ПМИ - программа методики испытаний, где вы опишите все что необходимо для проведения испытаний вашего продукта, чтобы убедиться, что он работает и удовлетворяет условия в ТЗ.
Есть также ЧТЗ -частное техническое задание, которое делается вами если вы дорабатываете существующее ПО по желанию заказчика.
В процессе создания всего этого вам надо будет отдельно записать пользовательские истории, описать UC (User Cases). Создать множество диаграмм, схем, в которых вы опишите текущее состояние архитектуры системы и далее состояние системы после внедрения.
Однозначно ответить на вопрос сложно, так как зависит от объема работ, от подхода в вашей компании.
И конечно нельзя забыть о руководстве пользователя.